# If $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $H \leq G$ for which $P \leq H$ then $P \in Syl_p(H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is exercise 4.5.1 in Dummit and Foote.

**Problem:** Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ containing $P$, show that $P \in Syl_p(H)$.

> *Attempt:* Becasue $P \leq H \leq G$ it follows that writing $|G| = p^rm$ where $p \nmid m$ we have that $|P| = p^r$ by definition of being a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Because of Lagrange's theorem $|P|$ divides the order of $H$ which divides the order of $G$ so that $|H| = p^rk$ for some $1 \leq k <m$ where $p \nmid k$ and $k\mid m$. So $P$ is also a subgroup of maximal prime power in $H$ i.e $P \in Syl_p(H)$.

Does this make sense? I want to make sure I have all of the steps understood even though I know the problem is trivial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks correct to me.